# How to use MVC properly on a mostly static website?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks

I'm using the Nette framework, which uses the MVC paradigm. Thing is, my site is supposed to be mostly static, just having a register/login form and a mini-forum/guestbook, other pages will be static. How do you properly employ the use of this paradigm on such sites? For one, I am not sure how many controllers/views I want for this or if there are supposed to be any models for the static parts. I also am not sure whether the static data should be hardcoded or if it should be grabbed from the database. Could anyone enlighten me about this? I have read many articles about MVC and understand how it should work in theory, but I can't apply it myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static page is just the view which will sent to the client by the controller, no model involved as there is no business logic. So what you will have is effectively VC, with the controller serving the view.

If you make your static pages from a template, then there won't be much work to do if you decide they need some dynamic content later.

Comment: So on the static pages, everything will be the same, except I won't need to ask the model for anything?

Comment: There isn't anything to ask for. There is no logic in a static page, just the HTML.

Comment: So if I get this right, instead of having a template and filling it with data I get from a model, with a static page I just have another template with the static data already in that I serve?